# What does "The most they can get from her" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I would like to know what "The most they
can get from her" means in the following sentences:

> It is a few moments before the waitress regains consciousness. She is,
> it appears, uninjured, but whatever she has seen out there has struck
> her nearly mute. **The most they can get from her** are low moans,
> wordless nonsense.
>
> ‘I sent her over to the Folly for a couple more bottles of champagne,’
> the head waitress – only twenty or so herself – says helplessly.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 13

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests gathered at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The wedding ceremony is held at the Folly, which is a renovated castle. On the wedding night, after several times of blackout, a waitress screams outside before entering the marquee, the party venue installed on the island, and guests are now all gathered to see what happened.

In this part, I am wondering what "the most they can get" means.
Is it similar to say "the best thing they can get"? Or "as many words as they can get"?

In short, I am finding it difficult to understand what "the most" means here.

Comment: *the most they can get = **all** they can get*. They can't get any more information or reassurance from the waitress than moaning and gibberish. In context, what they're *trying* to get could be some specific information that they're hoping she's just discovered, OR simply reassurance that she's not seriously injured. If you're reading the book, you'll know which of those applies (or feasibly *both*).

Comment: Dear @FumbleFingers, thank you very much for the explanation. I think I was confused because "most" can sometimes be used as a superlative as in "the most beautiful person on earth", and sometimes as a noun, meaning "nearly all" as in "most of the people", so I didn't know what to choose from. Then, may I take that "most" here means "everything," and is used like a superlative?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say *[the] **most*** actually "means" ***everything*** in your context. It just so happens that if I replace the first *two* words in the cited context with my suggested single word, we end up with a *sentence* that means the same. In fact, ***the most*** here very specifically implies ***significantly less than everything*** (they wanted to get ***more*** information from the waitress than they were actually ***able*** to get). But I think you understand this point anyway.

Comment: Dear @FumbleFingers, thank you very much for the explanation. Then the "most" implies the limit, meaning that it was the largest amount of information they can get from her, which was significantly less than what was required. I sincerely appreciate your help. :)

Comment: You have it exactly! I should say that ***I*** sincerely appreciate ***your*** final comment there, explaining *in your own words* how you now understand the word "more" in the cited context. The fact that you've expressed it so concisely and accurately proves to me that I wasn't wasting my time trying to get the message across! :)

Comment: Dear @FumbleFingers, thank you very much for the comment! I am so flattered by your compliment. I should say a great teacher makes a great student!  Thank you so much again for taking your time and explaining this to me.